I made addon using Chat gpt but missing manifest error kept showing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/109kpOQzqSEglV8A5OiIfuMZob2P_zRQN/view?usp=sharing
This is the addon i made with chat gpt and I think I have done everything by the book, but when I try to install addon, missing manifest file error is kept showing.
I don't know what is the problem and seems like chat gpt can't solve it either.

LLM have a cutoff date, which for chat GPT 4 is likely April 2023, at this date the new extensions system API wasn't implemented so you just can't do what you are trying to do with chatGPT, for now. There are some ressources online you can parse. Please share your code by text rather than having to access a random google drive link if you want some help. Cheers

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/extensions/getting_started.html

the link is private. It would be better to add the code to your question.
